# NSIS. Выход из установщика

Tags: windows, установка, nsis

Я определил кастомную функцию `abort` и хочу прервать установку.

```
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT customOnUserAbort

Function customOnUserAbort
    Quit (or Abort) #no matter
FunctionEnd
```

Также создана кастомная страница, где выполняются долгие по времени операция (скачивание файла) в фоновом режиме (отдельном потоке) в функции `MyCustomLeave` (при переходе на следующую страницу)

```
Function MyCustomLeave 
ShowWindow $UnderTopLabel 0 
ShowWindow $UnderTopLabel2 1

EnableWindow $CustomNext.Button 0

EnableWindow $RADIO1 0
EnableWindow $RADIO_LABEL1 0
EnableWindow $RADIO2 0
EnableWindow $RADIO_LABEL2 0
ShowWindow $GROUP1 ${SW_HIDE}

${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $unpackIndex $Checkbox_StateUnpackIndex

${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $hpIndex $Checkbox_StateSetUpHomepage
 ${if} $Checkbox_StateSetUpHomepage == 1
    StrCpy $ChangeHomepage 1
 ${else}
    StrCpy $ChangeHomepage 0
 ${endif}

${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $searchIndex $Checkbox_StateSetUpSearch
 ${if} $Checkbox_StateSetUpSearch == 1
    StrCpy $ChangeSearch 1
 ${else}
    StrCpy $ChangeSearch 0
 ${endif}

${NSD_LV_GetCheckState} $GROUP1 $ntIndex $Checkbox_StateSetUpNewTabPage
 ${if} $Checkbox_StateSetUpNewTabPage == 1
    StrCpy $ChangeNewTabPage 1
 ${else}
    StrCpy $ChangeNewTabPage 0
 ${endif}

 /*CUSTOM_PAGE_SOFT_3*/

Call ValidateCheckedExtraSoft

GetFunctionAddress $0 **workerfunc**
BgWorker::CallAndWait #in background
FunctionEnd
```

При нажатии кнопки "закрыть x" (красная в правом верхнем углу) срабатывает `customOnUserAbort`, появляется новое чистое серое окно, а инсталер не завершается пока до конца не выполнится `workerfunc`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно немедленно завершить установщик? Или как можно сделать кнопку "закрыть x" не активной? Или может какой другой грамотный вариант?

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Скажите, при чем тут вообще linux?

Comment: Не причем тут, полагаю ты мне ничем не поможешь